# BASH: keep connection alive

Tags: bash, shell, sockets, telnet, netcat

I have the following scenario:

I use `netcat` to connect to a host running `telnet` server on port 23, I log in using provided username and password, issue some commands, after which I need to do fairly complex analysis of the provided output. Naturally, `expect` comes to mind, with a script like this:

```
spawn nc host 23
send "user\r"
send "pass\r"
send "command\r"
expect EOF
```

then, it is executed with `expect example.scr >output.log`, so the output file can be parsed. The parser is 150+ lines of `bash` code that executes under 2 seconds, and makes a decision what command should be executed next. Thus, it replaces "command" with "command2", and executes the `expect` script again, like this:

```
sed -i '/send "command\r"/send "command2\r"/' example.scr
expect example.scr >output.log
```

Obviously, it is not needed to re-establish `telnet` connection and perform log in process all over again, just to issue a single `telnet` command after 2 seconds of processing. A conclusion can be made, that `telnet` session should be kept alive as a background process, so one could freely talk to it at any given time. Naturally, using `named pipes` comes to mind:

```
mkfifo in
mkfifo output.log
cat in | nc host 23 >output.log &
echo -e "user\npass\ncommand\n" >in
cat output.log
```

After the file is written to, `EOF` causes the `named pipe` to close, thus terminating the `telnet` session. I was thinking what kind of eternal process could be piped to `netcat` so it can be used as `telnet` relay to host. I came up with a very silly idea, but it works:

```
nc -k -l 666 | nc host 23 >output.log &
echo -e "user\npass\ncommand\n" | nc localhost 666
cat output.log
```

The `netcat` server is started with k(eep alive), listening on port 666, and any data stream is redirected to the `netcat` `telnet` client connected to the host, while the entire conversation is dumped to output.log. One can now `echo` telnet commands to `nc localhost 666`, and read the result from output.log.

One should keep in mind that the `expect` script can be easily modified to accommodate `SSH` and even `serial console` connection, just by spawning `ssh` or `socat` instead of `netcat`. I never liked `expect` because it forces a use of another scripting language within `bash`, requires `tcl` libraries, and needs to be compiled for the embedded platforms, while `netcat` is a part of `busybox` and readily available everywhere.

So, the question is - could this be done in a simpler way? I'd put my bet on having some sort of link between console and `TCP socket`. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Switching to Perl or Python would remove a number of complications.  There are expect-like libraries available for both.

Comment: "... because it forces a use of another scripting language within `bash` ...", "... and needs to be compiled for the embedded platforms, while `netcat` is a part of `busybox` and readily available everywhere", so I saw what `Python` has to offer, but it is not convenient for this particular purpose

Comment: `expect` is already a dependency, isn't it? A Python script and its dependencies can be "compiled" into a single blob, I believe, although I have only seen it done on Windows, with py2exe.

Comment: By the by, the `sed -i` seems wasteful and brittle. Why don't you `sed 's/send "command"/send "command2"/' example.scr | expect` (provided `expect` can take a script on stdin, and assuming your `sed` command is lacking the initial `s`, because the one you have doesn't parse)?

Comment: `expect` is a dependency I'd very much like to avoid. On the other hand, `sed` performs replacements on the script file because that file is being stitched together by several different scripts along the way...

Comment: I would just use `expect` for this and have it run the bash script on the output file and use its output as the next command to run. No need to modify the original script file, etc.

Answer (score 1):

How about using like a file descriptor?

```
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/host/port

while true; do
    echo -e "user\npass\ncommand" >&3
    read_response_generate_next_command <&3 >&3
    # if no more commands, break;
done

exec 3>&-
```